Eclipse gives me a classnotfoundexception everytime after saving a file
I have the most annoying problem in my eclipse: Everytime i edit a java file and save it my project somehow looses knowledge of some classes in my classpath. For example i am writing junit tests with mockito and after saving my test file and running the test i suddenly get: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MockedConstruction
Then i have to execute Project -> Clean and then everything runs normal again until i save a file again. Since i am saving files quite often during development you can imagine how annoying this can get. Since everything works after the clean the problem cannot be related to my dependency management in general because all the libs are where i expect them. I had this problem in multiple eclipse versions (currently 03/24) and workspaces. The only common thing the workspaces have is that i used the same workspace preferences file. I also tried running my eclipse in admin mode, but no difference. I am using Windows 10. Anybody got a solution for me?

Running Eclipse as administrator as a pretty bad idea since this can make files not accessible anymore for a regular user. I highly recommend to do a fresh installation of the current Eclipse 2024-06. What do you mean by "same workspace preferences file"? Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Is MockedConstruction something of yours? Or maybe something used by a plug-in that is no longer installed? Is there more details in the .log file in the .metadata of the workspace.
